# From .csv to .nc file using ncdf4 package (Error in ncvar_put)

Tags: r, arrays, ncdf4

I'm trying to write a `.nc` file from a `.csv` file.

This is PART of my `.csv` table (`df`)

```
 long        lat     elev
1  -47.99206  -7.501234 242.0362
2  -47.99206  -7.751234 200.7271
3  -47.99206  -8.001234 165.6918
4  -47.99206  -8.251234 271.2571
5  -47.99206  -8.501234 235.2896
6  -47.99206  -8.751234 271.5381
7  -47.99206  -9.001234 290.0054
8  -47.99206  -9.251234 218.8803
9  -47.99206  -9.501234 261.7539
10 -47.99206  -9.751234 318.0000
11 -47.99206 -10.001234 314.3667
12 -47.99206 -10.251234 386.0861
13 -47.99206 -10.501234 446.0594
14 -47.99206 -10.751234 733.0910
15 -47.99206 -11.001234 316.2924
16 -47.99206 -11.251234 264.8820
17 -47.74206  -7.501234 262.5883
18 -47.74206  -7.751234 197.8402
19 -47.74206  -8.001234 246.0610
20 -47.74206  -8.251234 264.7328

...
```

As you can see I have two dimensions and one variable.

This is the code I'm using:

```
xvals <- unique(df$long)
xvals <- xvals[order(xvals)]
yvals = unique(df$lat)
yvals <- yvals[order(yvals)] 

lon <- ncdim_def("longitude", "degrees", xvals)
lat <- ncdim_def("latitude", "degrees", yvals)

var_elev <- ncvar_def("elev", "m above sea", 
                      list(lon, lat), NA) 

ncnew <- nc_create('elev.nc', var_elev)

ncvar_put(ncnew, "elev", df$elev, count = c(35, 51))
```

When I run the last line, I get this error message:

```
Error in ncvar_put(ncnew, "elev", df$elev, count = c(35, 51)) : 
  ncvar_put: error: you asked to write 1785 values, but the passed data array only has 959 entries!
```

More information about my dimensions:

`yvals` unique values:

```
yvals
 [1] -15.001234 -14.751234 -14.501234 -14.251234 -14.001234
 [6] -13.751234 -13.501234 -13.251234 -13.001234 -12.751234
[11] -12.501234 -12.251234 -12.001234 -11.751234 -11.501234
[16] -11.251234 -11.001234 -10.751234 -10.501234 -10.251234
[21] -10.001234  -9.751234  -9.501234  -9.251234  -9.001234
[26]  -8.751234  -8.501234  -8.251234  -8.001234  -7.751234
[31]  -7.501234  -7.251234  -7.001234  -6.751234  -6.501234
[36]  -6.251234  -6.001234  -5.751234  -5.501234  -5.251234
[41]  -5.001234  -4.751234  -4.501234  -4.251234  -4.001234
[46]  -3.751234  -3.501234  -3.251234  -3.001234  -2.751234
[51]  -2.501234
```

`xvals` unique values:

```
xvals
 [1] -50.49206 -50.24206 -49.99206 -49.74206 -49.49206 -49.24206
 [7] -48.99206 -48.74206 -48.49206 -48.24206 -47.99206 -47.74206
[13] -47.49206 -47.24206 -46.99206 -46.74206 -46.49206 -46.24206
[19] -45.99206 -45.74206 -45.49206 -45.24206 -44.99206 -44.74206
[25] -44.49206 -44.24206 -43.99206 -43.74206 -43.49206 -43.24206
[31] -42.99206 -42.74206 -42.49206 -42.24206 -41.99206
```

And `elev` column has 959 unique values.

Additionaly, I'm not sure that reorder the dimensions will give me the right correspondence between `long`, `lat` and `elev`. Anyway, I'm completely lost how to solve this problem.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Hi, in the last line, I think `elev` should be `"elev"` (i.e. a string). Can you tell the size of  `var_elev` and the size of `df$elev`? They apparently do not match.

Comment: Yes sure, I made the correction and update the error message. The same error appears, however with different numbers. Also, `var_elev$varsize` returns `35 51`.

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to define a 2D array with ncdim_def, but only pass a 1D vector to the dataset. You need to convert the observations of your dataframe to a 2D array. This can be done with tidyr:

```
library(tidyr)
# Example df with same names
df <- data.frame(long = rep(1:10,2), lat = 1:40, elev = 1:40)
# Creates a 2D array
df_new <- tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from = long, values_from = elev)
df_new <- df_new[,-1]
```

Now try

```
ncvar_put(ncnew, elev, as.matrix(df_new))
```

Comment: I tried to implement your solution with no success. I get the following error: `Error in ncvar_put(ncnew, varid = "elev", vals = df_new) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'`

Comment: In the ncvar_put function call, change df_new to as.matrix(df_new), i forgot about that.